# assigning default constructor value from another constructor from different classes

Tags: java, constructor

I need to assign default values stored in my first class constructor to second class constructor 
following shows my second class from where i am calling `Guest` class constructors default value.

```
public class AuditoriumSeating {
   Guest[][] seating;

   public AuditoriumSeating(int rowNum, int columnNum) {
      seating = new Guest[rowNum][columnNum];
      Guest c;
      for ( int i=0; i < rowNum; i++ ) {
         for( int j=0; j < columnNum; j++ ) {
            seating[i][j] = ;   
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But the problem is I can not figure out what to assign `seating[i][j]` with, so I can assign this array `seating[][]` with a default constructor value that I have assigned in my previous class constructor.
Here is my guest class constructor:

```
public class Guest {

   public String lastName;
   public String firstName;

   public Guest()
   {
      firstName="???";
      lastName="???";
   }
}
```

Comment: please post your Guest class

Comment: And it's not clear what you're asking. As far as I can tell, you just want `seating[i][j] = new Guest(/*...you can put args here if necessary...*/);`...?

Comment: Please make your variables private and access them with getter and setter methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Guest` should assign whatever default you think best, perhaps `null`:

```
public Guest() {
    firstName = null;
    lastName = null;
}
```

And your code creating it:

```
seating[i][j] = new Guest();
```

**But**:

- `Guest` should probably provide a constructor that accepts the initial value to assign those as arguments

  ```
  public Guest(String _firstName, String _lastName) {
      firstName = _firstName;
      lastName = _lastName;
  }
  ```
- `Guest`'s `firstName` and `lastName` probably shouldn't be `public`; instead, make them `private` and use accessor functions. Opinions can vary on this, but it's the overwhelming convention in Java, and don't worry, the JVM is **very** good at making those accessors efficient.
- (Subjective) Opinions vary, but I find always explicitly using `this` when referencing instance members helps avoid confusion between variables, arguments, and instance members:

  ```
  public Guest(String firstName, String lastName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
  }
  ```

  Again, though, that's a matter of opinion and style.